# Vue Tailwind Datapicker -> How can I change the rounding/specific color on selected dates?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vue-component, tailwind-css

I want to change the rounding of selected data to be more square. Also how can i use specify color in tailwind.config file to be compatibile with this component? Because for now that vtd-primary color doesn't work

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: I forked the package's playground environment and customized as written in this answer. You can see how it works [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-tailwind-datepicker-9vk8s4?file=tailwind.config.js).

Notice how I changed the `500` part of the color to black in the tailwind config. Also, the button style override is in the `index.css` file.

**What I did:**

For your first question, you can override the rounding by declaring the following css in your component or global styles:

```
button.vtd-datepicker-date {
  @apply rounded-lg;
}
```

Update the rounded class as you wish.

In terms of adjusting the color, it appears that the package accepts an entire color object, rather than a string of hex code.
From the official documentation, colors.sky returns the Tailwind color palette of 50 - 900.

In that case, `'vtd-primary': colors.sky` essentially returns

```
'vtd-primary': {
    '50': "#f0f9ff",
    '100': "#e0f2fe",
    '200': "#bae6fd",
    '300': "#7dd3fc",
    '400': "#38bdf8",
    '500': "#000", // changed this to black
    '600': "#0284c7",
    '700': "#0369a1",
    '800': "#075985",
    '900': "#0c4a6e"
}
```

Now, for you to customize, you should create a color palette of your desired color (if Tailwind does not already have something that matches it); then you pass the colors (from 50-900) in an object as shown above.

You can simply copy and paste the object above and modify to your colors.

I hope this solves your problem.

Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately, no solution worked. I use this component:
 https://vue-tailwind-datepicker.com/ and unfortunately it shows that apply cannot be used

Comment: Oh I tested before dropping the comment. I use the same package too. The "@apply" needs to go in your css file or append it in component based <style> </style> tag. Both solutions worked while I tested. Maybe I need to understand your codebase more. Mind putting it on codepen or codesandbox so I can assist to troubleshoot? Once again, the two solutions I provided using the same package worked perfectly here..

Comment: I updated the answer to show you how it works. You can check the link :)

Comment: And maybe do you know is it possible to change color of range between dates?

Comment: Yah, I think you would need to adjust the '100' part of the color for that. Try it

Comment: Yes, thank you! And one more question. Do you know is it possible to move calendar icon to left side?

Comment: I guess you would need to do some more hacking for that one. Maybe try using custom slots to achieve this? Covered in the [docs](https://vue-tailwind-datepicker.com/props.html#slot)

Comment: Okey, i will try. Thank you one more time!